# Need help with ratio calculation

Tags: ratio

I have 2 objects with the width of:

> Object 1 = 375
>
> Object 2 = 359

If I change Object 1 width to 333.5, what would object 2 be?

This is probably really simple, but I'm trying to get the answer to be 311. Please explain answer. Thanks!

Comment: far from being simple, I'm certain it is impossible without more information.

Comment: The answer would be 19, correct?

Comment: This is assuming the ratio of width of object 1 to width of object 2 is constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the ratio between the widths of the two objects to be preserved, let $x$ be the new width of Object $2$, so

$$\frac{375}{359}=\frac{333.5}{x}$$

Can you solve this for $x$?

Comment: does x = 19...?

Comment: @Jessica Plug in $x=19$ into the equation. Does it work?

Comment: I meant x = 319?

Comment: Yes. It is not *exactly* 319 but, depending on how much precision you need, it may not matter